# Symfony easyadmin ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on production server

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I implemented the admin panel using a EasyAdminBundle 3.0 version.

I have the following controller with routing annotation:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/dashboard", name="admin")
 */
public function index():Response
{
    $routeBuilder = $this->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);

    return $this->redirect($routeBuilder->setController(UserCrudController:>
}
```

Another route is working fine, only easyadmin routes are not working. This works fine on my development server. However, on my production server, I get an infinite redirect route. I looked through the logs and it is caused by Symfony, not Apache. It does this over and over until my browser stops

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when i put in prod and finally it was solved by adding a slash to the route name

```
 /**
 * @Route("/admin/dashboard", name="admin/")
 */
public function index():Response
{
    $routeBuilder = $this->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);

    return $this->redirect($routeBuilder->setController(UserCrudController:>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in the last post. It was like this in my controller. Not the name but the path. My bad, sorry.

```
/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
 * @Route("/admin/", name="admin")
 */
public function index():Response
{
    $routeBuilder = $this->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);

    return $this->redirect($routeBuilder->setController(UserCrudController:>
}
```

Comment: If that's typo, I think that's likely not the case.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo but on localhost it works fine.

Comment: well it on your localhost not on every localhost tho

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo it not only on my localhost

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for dev and prod.
My problem was in nginx.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php;
}
```

It was solved by changing nginx configs.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php?$query_string;
}
```